# error al iniciar sesión en aplicación laravel 8

Tags: php, linux, laravel-8, apache2

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en Laravel 8, al virtualizar el host en mi local  se inicia correctamente, pero al iniciar sesión me da error 404 la configuración de mi archivo apache2.conf con es la siguiente

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/08002/public
ServerName 0800.local
</VirtualHost>
```

y en el archivo /etc/hosts coloque esta linea

```
127.0.0.1 0800.local
```

La pagina de login carga correctamente, pero al iniciar sesión me da error 404, no se si sea por que falta configurar algo en los archivos anteriormente nombrados o sea el archivo web.php en el proyexto

respuesta del servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando te aparezca el error 404 fíjate bien la url que aparece en la barra de url de arriba, y si cumple con lo esperado (quizas intenta enviarte a otra parte tu propio código). Si no lo ves claro [edit] la pregunta y pégala para que la veamos nosotros también y podamos deducir mejor que te pasa.

Comment: http://0800.local/Userlogin esta en la ruta que me aparece en la consola, por que en la url del navegador no se refleja nada mas